# How to query a One to Many to Many to One to Many to One and match info from the first table, and the last table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, rdbms

I have Table that is a one to Many on cross ref table, which is then a many to one on another table.  Then that table has a one to Many on another table and then there is a one to one between that table.

So think of it like this:

People -> crossref <- Dog Breeds -> Many Different Dogs -> Dog Name

And what I want to associate is Person -> Dog Name with no duplication of the same dog name per person.

Like how many distinct dog names does the person use.  And I don't want to use distinct because it is slow.  I want the query to be instant or near instant.  The obvious choice would be to change the data model with a cross ref between people and dog names, but lets pretend that is not an option.  All tables have indexed IDs so like Person.id, etc.

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result/

Comment: Why do you think that using distinct is slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ERD is incorrect.  Instead it should read as follows:

```
Person <1:M> dog <1:1 or 1:M> dog breed
```

A person owns one or many dogs.  A dog is of a single breed (well, I guess you can make it one-to-many if you consider mixed muts).  From this design, you can then easily answer which person owns what dogs AND the various breeds.  In your design above, there is not a natural relationship between person and breed.

Comment: I get the feeling my dog example wasn't a great one :) That being said I figured out a way to do it efficiently.